# Merge or combine associative array childs

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have an associative array I would like to merge (combine). The actual code is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id_Usager] => 291
            [etat_lundi] => livree
            [Date_lundi] => 2011-12-26
            [etat_mardi] => livree
            [Date_mardi] => 2011-12-27
            [etat_mercredi] => livree
            [Date_mercredi] => 2011-12-28
            [etat_jeudi] => livree
            [Date_jeudi] => 2011-12-29
            [etat_vendredi] => livree
            [Date_vendredi] => 2011-12-30
            [etat_samedi] => livree
            [Date_samedi] => 2011-12-31
            [etat_dimanche] => livree
            [Date_dimanche] => 2012-01-01
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id_Usager] => 291
            [etat_lundi] => livree
            [Date_lundi] => 2012-01-02
            [etat_mardi] => livree
            [Date_mardi] => 2012-01-03
            [etat_mercredi] => en_cours
            [Date_mercredi] => 2012-01-04
            [etat_jeudi] => en_cours
            [Date_jeudi] => 2012-01-05
            [etat_vendredi] => en_cours
            [Date_vendredi] => 2012-01-06
            [etat_samedi] => en_cours
            [Date_samedi] => 2012-01-07
            [etat_dimanche] => en_cours
            [Date_dimanche] => 2012-01-08
        )

)
```

What I want at the end is:

1. Unset the first element (`Id_Usager`)
2. Merge the subarray into one
3. Compat pairs, by moving `etat` value (`[etat_lundi] => livree`) as `Date` key (`[Date_lundi] => 2012-01-02`)

The resulting array I want to have is this:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [livree] => 2011-12-26
        [livree] => 2011-12-27
        [livree] => 2011-12-28
        [livree] => 2011-12-29
        [livree] => 2011-12-30
        [livree] => 2011-12-31
        [livree] => 2012-01-01
        [livree] => 2012-01-02
        [livree] => 2012-01-03
        [en_cours] => 2012-01-04
        [en_cours] => 2012-01-05
        [en_cours] => 2012-01-06
        [en_cours] => 2012-01-07
        [en_cours] => 2012-01-08
    )
)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: That doesn't make sense because keys must be unique.

Comment: Dude in your required resultent array there are two-two entries with same id and different value..How is that possible.. [Date_mardi] => 2011-12-27 [Date_mercredi] => 2012-01-04

Comment: As everyone here has pointed out this is not possible. You may want to try making duplicate keyed-items part of an array (so [0]['Id_Usager'] = array(291,291)) but this depends on what you are trying to do. Why do you want the array formatted this way?

Comment: You're right guys! Sorry for not noticing this. My bad!

Comment: I've modified my demand to be more precise.

Comment: Your updated resulting array is not possible either. **Key names must be unique per array dimension/level.**

Comment: @knibals I am voting to close as your desired result is something that can not possibly exist in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/array_merge)

In your case:

```
$new_data = array_merge($data[0], $data[1]);
```

Note that per the docs:

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one.

From your sample data it appears that you have duplicate key names (which is not possible as noted by **Ben D**). However, they contain the same value. So you *should* be okay.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking. The user is asking for an impossible task: creating an array with multiple elements identified by the same key.

Comment: @Ben D, I believe it is. The user just needs to be educated that duplicate keys are as you said, *impossible*. I have clearly noted that.

Comment: apologies. My display only showed "array_merge()" with no explanation. The updated answer is correct. I'll remove the -1 in a moment.

Comment: Apparently I don't have the ability to remove my vote unless the answer is edited. If you make a nominal change I'll remove the -1. Sorry for the hassle.

Comment: Interesting, you should just be able to unclick your down vote. All the same, see update.

Comment: There we go. When I tried it early it threw a warning that because my vote had sat for a few minutes it was locked unless edits were made. In any case, +2

Comment: Thank you all. My bad for the mess. I've raffined my request to be more explicit.